# Smoothly zoom a big Image with SDL

Tags: c++, zooming, sdl

I need to smoothly zoom in/out and pan an image (for a slideshow) with the sdl library.

I've tried rotozoom from the SDL GFX library but it's far away from smooth.

What would be the best approach here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "vanilla" SDL seems too slow for you I'd suggest switching your drawing code to OpenGL. That way you'll get hardwareaccelleration and your issues should go away:)

Using OpenGL coupled with SDL is very easy and there are lots of tutorials on how to do it.